# SQL/Oracle 10g - Issue with assertion

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm currently having an issue implementing a simple task in which a new job from an existing client is not approved until they have paid their debt. I thought this would've been simple until I found out that SQL-92 assertions don't work in Oracle...

I've looked around the web and saw that it was possible to do the same thing but with triggers/check constraints. However, I'm completely lost on how to achieve this.

My database is structured like so:

```
Table invoice is in a one-to-many relationship with jobs
Table jobs is in a many-to-one relationship with client
```

At the moment I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_debt
BEFORE UPDATE ON jobs
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ((SELECT * FROM client WHERE clientNo =
(SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobNo =
(SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE status = 'Debt Owing'))))
COMMIT;
```

As you can see, I have no idea how to mimic an assertion with a trigger...

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

**NOTE:** I'm practicing using SQL-92 and SQL-99 standards.

Comment: Can you explain in words what you're trying to assert in this trigger?  I'm having trouble understanding what the goal of this trigger is.  It would probably also help to define the four tables here (`client`, `jobNo`, `invoice`, and `jobs`)

Comment: Sorry, there is actually 3 tables (jobNo was supposed to be jobs.. my bad). Basically, I want to assert that a job can not be accepted from an existing client (client have multiple job proposals) unless their previous job invoices has been paid (thus status in invoice is "debt owing"). Hope that cleared it up abit more

Answer (score 1):

When you do the update on jobs include the query to check the status of the invoices.

```
update jobs
  set ...
where ... -- logic to select job to update
and   not exists (
        select *
        from   invoice
        where  ... -- insert join condition
        and    status = 'Debt Owing')
```

then check whether a row was updated (method depends on what client you're using).

Comment: I can sort of see how this would work, but I'm using sqldeveloper and just using the interface to insert/update/delete rows

Comment: sqldeveloper allows you to run an update statement - just paste it into the sql editor and click the green "run" button.